# How to decrease the runtime of this following code?

Tags: java, runtime

(This program needs to accept N inputs of two numbers in one line, where the first number is a runner's instantaneous time in seconds and instantaneous distance. From these values, it will output the fastest speed between two consecutive points.)

I need to decrease the runtime of this program. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;

 public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {

  BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

     int x = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
     double n1;
     double n2;
     double placeholder = 0;
     double maxspeed = 0;
     int[] time = new int[x];
     int[] distance = new int[x];

     for(int i = 0; i<x; i++) {

       String userinput= input.readLine();

       String[] parts = userinput.split(" ");
       String part1 = parts[0];
       time[i] = Integer.parseInt(part1);
       String part2 = parts[1];
       distance[i] = Integer.parseInt(part2);
       }

     for (int j = 0; j< distance.length; j++) {
       for(int i = 1; i< distance.length; i++) {

         n1 = (distance[(distance.length-1)- j] - distance[(distance.length-1) - i]);
         n2 = (time[(time.length-1) - j] - time[(time.length-1) - i]) ;

         if ((n2 != 0) && (n1/2 != n1)) {
           placeholder = (n1 / n2);
           if(placeholder < 0) {
             placeholder = placeholder*-1;
           }

           if(placeholder > maxspeed) {
             maxspeed = placeholder;
           }

         }
       }
     }
     System.out.println(maxspeed);
   }
 }
```

Comment: Why are you traversing the arrays from the back?  Just use `distance[j]` instead of `distance[(distance.length-1)-j]` and so on.  You'll traverse all the values eventually, just in a different order.  And `n1/2 != n1` looks strange - isn't that just `n1 != 0`?

Comment: If you are trying to find the max ratio, maximize the numerator, minimize the denominator. You can do both of those things independently, then divide at the end.

Comment: "From these values, it will output the fastest speed between two consecutive points" your program isn't doing this. You don't need nested loops to do that, just calculate the delta of distance and time since the previous point.

Comment: @Andy I don't think that doing numerator and denominator separately will do the job (e.g. if max numerator is at index `i` and min denominator at `j` (`!= i`), or, with number `10/10`;`20/15` should be `20/15` not `20/10`)